# LINQ query returns error "The expected type was 'System.Int32' but the actual value was null."

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.0

So this is the query:

```
from c in Contents
join cs in DepartmentSharings 
on c.ContentId equals cs.ContentId
select c.PrivateCategoryId.Value
```

When I run this I get:

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a
>   database value for property 'DepartmentSharing.ContentId'. The
>   expected type was 'System.Int32' but the actual value was null.

Now I checked the `DepartmentSharings.ContentId` field in the database, its `fk, int, not null`. In the class it's `public int ContentId { get; set; }`. `DepartmentSharing.ContentId` cannot be `null`. Also, in LinqPad I can see it returns 58 rows before failing.
 Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I'm dubious about that error message, because the generated SQL for that would have *no reason* to ever fetch that value - that would just be part of the `join` - something like `select c.PrivateCategoryId from Contents c inner join DepartmentSharings cs on c.ContentId = cs.ContentId`. Are you sure the real problem isn't the `PrivateCategoryId` being `null`?

Comment: If you can see it returns 58 rows before failing you might want to look at the data in the 59th row to see what it looks like and whether it looks funny at all...

Comment: can you capture sql query fired using profiler and run that in ssms directly to quick check result

Comment: I think it's this one: `select c.PrivateCategoryId.Value`. `c.PrivateCategoryId` might be null.

Comment: @MarcGravell that's EF Core, which can execute query in memory if it cannot traslate it (and it cannot VERY often), so maybe real OP query is a bit more complex, or, how knows, maybe EF Core cannot translate even this one for some reason (for example we don't know what `Contents` and `DepartmentSharings` are).

Comment: @MarcGravell and @Silvermind you were right. the problem was in `c.PrivateCategoryId`. I just added `when c.PrivateCategoryId.HasValue` and it works. Very strange how this error pointed at a different field.. Please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ShiranDror I doubt that this is a fix, it seems more like a work-around. I'm curious if switching the order of `on` clause would change anything: `cs.ContentId equals c.ContentId`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I can't change the order. `The name 'cs' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only thing that will cause that error is if `ContentId` is a non-nullable int property, but somehow your database table is allowing NULL values for that column. Assuming EF is handling your database, that shouldn't happen, but it's possible you've changed something at some point and didn't migrate properly.

Regardless, you need to either change the property type to `int?` instead of `int` or alter the table to make the column NOT NULL and ensure all the rows have a non-NULL value.

Comment: This worked for me on EntityFrameworkCore with a procedure db call using 'context.object.FromSql("Exec dbo.MyProcedure")'

It looks like it does NOT matter if Query always brings back a result or not, you will always get this error. 

As @Chris said, simply change the following and it should fix your issue.
public int Value{ get; set; }
to
public int? Value{ get; set; }

Answer (score -1):

Chris's answer looks sensible and correct but I have another experience.

I have two tables, they are related. The field with problem is match (*not a key but like a key*) field. Property is set non-nullable and related database field is same too. The problem occured because of there was no any related data with first table in second table. So, comparing two fields was causing problem. Actually this case is not expected but test data was corrupted. Even so, I added another condition before existing condition as "if data exists" and problem is gone.